# Нужно ли создавать для каждого блока отдельный контроллер, модель?

Tags: php, mvc

Есть сайт с новостями, видео, фото и так далее...
Вот примерная структура сайта

[image: img]

Нужно ли создавать для каждого блока отдельный контроллер, модель?

Answer (score 2):

Очевидно же, что если вы не сможете привести это всё к одному универсальному виду *(зачем?)*, то придётся написать свои контроллеры, модели, отображения.

Делайте вложенные отображения: Страница, у которой будут изменяемые блоки, вроде Контента, но статические шапка и футер.
Либо разбейте отображение на блоки, которые можно считать отдельными (шапка, футер, контент часть, сайдбар) и потом их собирайте в контроллере. Но это не очень гибкое/удобное/красивое решение.

Возьмите какой-то фреймворк со встроенным шаблонизатором и пользуйтесь - он вас научит что и где должно быть.

Comment: Подробнее можно?)

Comment: Вы путаете модель (model), занимающуюся работой с данными и отображение (view), которое всё и.. эм.. отображает :)

Comment: А как можно собирать их в контроллере?

Comment: Это ужасно, но так, например.

    $header = // формирование;
    $content = // формирование;
    $footer = // формирование;
    // остальное
    $response = $header.$content.$footer;

Comment: А можно MVC структуру написать процедурным PHP? то есть не используя ООП

Comment: Не делайте глупостей, о которых потом будете жалеть. Хотите MVC - учите ООП, смотрите примеры, пользуйтесь фреймворком :)

Comment: Точнее код писать функциями, а не классами и объектами

Comment: Всё можно, но зачем это нужно? Не хотите учиться - пишите как знаете, но только если после вас никто с этим кодом работать не будет.

Answer (score 1):

Да конечно, во избежания коллизий имен в методах контроллера/моделей, практикуйте, откроются идеи и будете упрощать код со временем.

Comment: Можешь примерно набросать, каким образом подключать файлы? как щаблон прикрутить?

Comment: я использую MVC фреймворк codeigniter

Answer (score 0):

Я могу ошибаться, но по моему следует разделить модули на те, что будут у вас на каждой странице и те которые на некоторых. И подключать в родительском те модули, которые вам нужны. В дочернем же следует рассматривать только специфические задачи для контроллера.

Comment: допустим, у меня есть фото и видеогалерея
надо создать две модели для них? т.е. foto_model.php и video_model.php?

Comment: да лучше разделять для каждой задачи модели в том числе для отображения списка/сетки и отдельного видео. хотя тут я могу и ошибаться, но я предпочитаю делать так.